# Grabbing date from p4 changes command

Tags: perforce

I am trying to grab the date, CL and user of a list of changelists submitted within a given timeframe.

```
p4 changes -s submitted //depot/mainline/... @2020/03/09,@2020/03/14
```

will give me the changes with a date but too much other information. So you can use -F to strip out the information delivered.

```
p4 -F %change%-%user%-%date% changes -s submitted //depot/mainline/... @2020/03/09,@2020/03/14
```

But irritatingly **-F %date%** does not mean "what date was this submitted?" it means "*what date is it today?*" This is despite the information on the **-e** flag telling me that **%date%** is the submitted date.

So any ideas on how to get the submitted date from the **-F** flag?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're on Windows and `%date%` is getting expanded by the shell so that `p4` never sees it:

```
C:\Perforce\test>echo %date%
Thu 03/19/2020
```

Escaping the `%` will prevent that and let `p4` see the command you actually wanted to run.  In the `cmd` shell you can escape `%` as `^%`:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 -F ^%date^% changes -m1
2020/03/16
```